# conditionally load a default static image if image metabox has no value

Tags: php

i have this basic while loop for my posts

```
<?php

         if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

         $title = get_the_title();

         $article = apply_filters( 'the_content', get_the_content() );

         $date = get_the_date();

         $source = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_articles_url', true );

         $img = wp_get_attachment_image( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_articles_image_id', 1 ), 'full', 1, get_post_meta($attachment_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true) );


    ?>
```

i want to write a conditional to check if $img has a value or not , and to load a static default image in case of $img is empty.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the get_post_meta() function reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) in the WordPress Codex, "If there is nothing to return the function will return an empty array unless $single has been set to true, in which case an empty string is returned."

That means we can use [ternary operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) to check whether `get_post_meta()` returns an empty string, and if so then we assign the static image instead. We'll only need to modify the line where the `$img` variable is defined:

```
$img = 
  ( '' == get_post_meta($attachment_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true) )
  ?
  get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/default-img.png' // updated example per comment
  :
  wp_get_attachment_image( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_articles_image_id', 1 ), 'full', 1, get_post_meta($attachment_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true) )
  ;
```

Comment: this is great , very useful operator . but i'm still facing one more problem which is adding the static image reference the src of the image should have ( echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>images/default-img.png ) when i inspect the img element it is putting the whole code as a src insted of processing it , not really sure what i am doing wrong

Comment: At this point, you're not trying to echo text to the browser -- you're trying to set the value of a variable. You need to append `/images/default-img.png` as a string to the end of what's returned by `get_template_directory_uri()` (the function doesn't put a forward slash at the end, so you need that at the beginning of whatever you're appending to it) and assign that full value to the `$img` variable. So here's how that line would look:

`?
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/default-img.png'
    :`

Comment: yeah i was trying to concat strings with `get_template_directory_uri()` but was getting syntax errors but i got it figured out now `'<img ' . 'src="' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/default-img.png"' . '>'` thanks alot for your help .